# What Kind of time format is this

Tags: php

I am getting some data from some api and I am  getting time in following formats/

```
PT127M
PT95M
```

which means 127 minutes and 95 minutes respectively.I want to get 127 from this with default functions.Right now I am using shortcut like below

```
$duration = "PT127M";
$duration = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$duration);
```

Some one tell me what kind of format is this and if there is any php function available to retrieve the minutes from it.

Comment: Looks like an API specific, is it not mentioned in the API docs?

Comment: No , I thought its some standard time format

Comment: Weird, I cannot recall on of these formats, except 1 that is used in event durations.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're currently doing it?

Comment: I found a reference to it in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt as trigger relative. But @jurgemaister is right, if it works, why bother?

Comment: @dmaij : what if API returns something with P1D22M , So I will be safe with php functions.

Answer (score 4):

It might be related to [ISO 8601 Duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) date format:

> To resolve ambiguity, "P1M" is a one-month duration and "PT1M" is a one-minute duration (note the time designator, T, that precedes the time value). The smallest value used may also have a decimal fraction, as in "P0.5Y" to indicate half a year. This decimal fraction may be specified with either a comma or a full stop, as in "P0,5Y" or "P0.5Y". The standard does not prohibit date and time values in a duration representation from exceeding their "carry over points" except as noted below. Thus, "PT36H" could be used as well as "P1DT12H" for representing the same duration. But keep in mind that "PT36H" is not the same as "P1DT12H" when switching from or to Daylight saving time.

You can use [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) to parse in PHP:

> Here are some simple examples. Two days is P2D. Two seconds is PT2S. Six years and five minutes is P6YT5M.

With this information you can parse your `$duration` object with this code:

```php
$duration = 'PT127M';
$duration = new DateInterval($duration); // Create a DateInteval Object
echo $duration->format('%i'); // Print minutes from DateInterval Object
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get minutes like this:

```
    $duration = 'PT127M';
    $di = new DateInterval($duration);
    $minutes =  $di->format('%i');
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: How is this different from Florian's answer?

Comment: We were posting simultaneously. I edited my answer with code after testing ;)

Comment: Florian edited his answer after this one was posted. Also, I am not using the same variable for different object types :)